# How do you auto size columns of a grid for PDF format in Birt reporting

Tags: eclipse, birt

I am working on a report in Birt reporting using Birt 4.5 in eclipse.

I have a grid that has 3 columns and inside each column is a label with some hard coded value to give you a test scenario,I also set the "Can shrink" property to true, and I did change the layout Preference to auto-Layout,  see pic bellow.

[image]

Now when I run this example as a Html out of eclipse I get the following and it works exactly like I want it to. It auto sizes the columns so the first column size has increased and the last 2 decreased.

Html pic :

[image]

Now I actually want it as a PDF format but the columns doesn't auto resize.

PDF pic :

[image]

I want this functionality because my report is going to be dynamic.

Is it possible to get the same result in the pdf format as html? If it is what properties should I set or how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
Those columns with no width specified (in your example: all three) take the remaining width (after considering the columns with a specified width) to equal parts.